# How to create multiple instances of eclipse information center?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

We are using eclipse information center for our help system. I am trying to set up multiple instances for different plugins using the steps in http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fua_help_setup_infocenter.htm.

There is a snip in section Running multiple instances of an information center in the above link.

"Multiple instances of an information center can be run on a machine from one installation. Each started instance must use its own port and must be provided with a workspace, hence the -port and -data options must be specified. The instances can serve documentation from different sets of plug-ins by providing a valid platform configuration with the -configuration option. "

Can somone please guide on how to create a new instance and values to be specified in -data and -configuration param?

Note: I have a help doc plugin and am able to bring it up in single instance. However for single instance you dont need to specify -data or -configuration param.

Thanks

Comment: I have 2 help guide plugins in c:\eclipse\plugins folder and i want each plugin to be separate instance. I want help guide 1 to be accessed in http://localhost:PORT1/help/topic and help guide 2 to be accessed in http://localhost:PORT2/help/topic

Comment: Why? If I were a user of your system, I would be totally confused by having multiple help systems running.

Comment: @Bananeweizen the help systems are for different products

Comment: Found the way to configure multiple instances of help docs with single installation.As specified in the url (in my question) we need to add -configuration param. However the catch lies in modifying the configuration folder. C:\eclipse>java -classpath c:/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.100.v201209141800.jar org.eclipse.help.standalone.Infocenter -command start -clean -data C:/Users/bharatwaj/workspace2 -port 8082 -configuration file:/c:/configuration_doc1 After running the above command a new config folder will be created in c directory.

Comment: Now what you need to do is go to C:\configuration_doc1\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator and edit bundle.info file for required plugins. Also please ensure to delete the configuration folder from c:/eclipse. This will override the confiuration folder that is passed in command line argument.